# css3 transition dropdown onclick

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, onclick, transition

In the following example when you click ***Click me***, a navigation menu opens.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxY2L/)

Does anyone know how to apply a css3 transition dropdown effect to the ***navigation-dropdown***, since there is no ***:onclick*** in css?*****

* while keeping ***navigation-dropdown*** on an auto height (I don't want a fixed height for the dropdown menu).

**Code:** (See example for the entire code)

```
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="navigation-sub">Click me</div>
</div>

<div id="navigation-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link four</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link six</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link eight</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link nine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link ten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link eleven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link twelve</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="X"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just toggle a class on click and use a transition.

**CSS**

```
#navigation-dropdown {
    transition: 3s ease-out;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
function dropIt() {
    toggleClass(document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown'), "hide");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxY2L/6/)**

Comment: That seems to work, but there's only one problem: ***navigation-dropdown*** needs to be hidden before you click, now it's there from the start.

Comment: Just add the `hide` class to your HTML?

Comment: Added the hide class to ***navigation-dropdown*** but now it doesn't work properly anymore [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pxY2L/8/)

Comment: That's because the height is measured at startup for the transition to work. You could define a height or measure it once after it expanded.

Comment: Could you use an auto height? Or something that isn't fixed? If so, could you show me in the example?

Comment: I've set the hide class to 100% height, this works but now the dropdown effect shows partly. Take a look: [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxY2L/9/) Do you know how to make this better?